# ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'stopImmediatePropagation' of object '[object Object]'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-universal

I am trying to integrate angular universal into my angular6 project. I followed the documentation ( and also the example project for angular universal on the same page, https://angular.io/guide/universal ).

Build is successful without any problem and runs fine too. But when I call localhost:4000, it throws this error,

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'stopImmediatePropagation' of object '[object Object]'
at DomEventsPlugin.patchEvent (/home/kushalgbk/Desktop/savemonk/savemonkWebsite/Savemonk-Mobile-Website-V2.0/dist/server.js:84969:50)
at new DomEventsPlugin (/home/kushalgbk/Desktop/savemonk/savemonkWebsite/Savemonk-Mobile-Website-V2.0/dist/server.js:84956:15)
at /home/kushalgbk/Desktop/savemonk/savemonkWebsite/Savemonk-Mobile-Website-V2.0/dist/server.js:60393:1533
at _callFactory (/home/kushalgbk/Desktop/savemonk/savemonkWebsite/Savemonk-Mobile-Website-V2.0/dist/server.js:13158:28)
at _createProviderInstance$1 (/home/kushalgbk/Desktop/savemonk/savemonkWebsite/Savemonk-Mobile-Website-V2.0/dist/server.js:13104:26)
at resolveNgModuleDep (/home/kushalgbk/Desktop/savemonk/savemonkWebsite/Savemonk-Mobile-Website-V2.0/dist/server.js:13067:21)
at _createClass (/home/kushalgbk/Desktop/savemonk/savemonkWebsite/Savemonk-Mobile-Website-V2.0/dist/server.js:13131:29)
at _createProviderInstance$1 (/home/kushalgbk/Desktop/savemonk/savemonkWebsite/Savemonk-Mobile-Website-V2.0/dist/server.js:13101:26)
at resolveNgModuleDep (/home/kushalgbk/Desktop/savemonk/savemonkWebsite/Savemonk-Mobile-Website-V2.0/dist/server.js:13067:21)
at _createClass (/home/kushalgbk/Desktop/savemonk/savemonkWebsite/Savemonk-Mobile-Website-V2.0/dist/server.js:13137:32)
```

**server.ts**

```
// These are important and needed before anything else
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';

import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

// Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
enableProdMode();

// Express server
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist/server/main');

// Express Engine
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
// Import module map for lazy loading
import { provideModuleMap } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));

// TODO: implement data requests securely
app.get('/api/*', (req, res) => {
  res.status(404).send('data requests are not supported');
});

// Server static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser')));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

I can post any other files if required.

**AppServerModule**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerModule } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { ModuleMapLoaderModule } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule,
    ServerModule,
    ModuleMapLoaderModule
  ],
  providers: [
    // Add universal-only providers here
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
})
export class AppServerModule {}
```

Comment: Can we see the code for the `AppServerModule`

Comment: I have added AppServerModule. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @okcomputer_kid were you able to resolve the above issue?

Comment: @PrabhatMishra Yes. I could resolve the issue. I will post it down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official documentation doesn't mention to add `ServerTransferStateModule` in app.server.module.ts
That made the difference.
Follow this sample project.

https://github.com/angular/universal-starter

Also, the github issue link( I closed once it was resolved)

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11273

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's a conflict between platform-server and angular/core downgrading(make sure both are same versions.) your platform-server to your angular/core version might help you to resolve the issue.